# Connect() function in Python is not working in Linux

Tags: python, linux, windows, python-3.x, connection

Following is the Server and Client code written for Python 3

Server code:

```
import sys
from socket import socket, gethostbyname, AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM

PORT_NUMBER = 5060
SIZE = 1024

hostName = gethostbyname( '0.0.0.0' )

recvSocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM )
recvSocket.bind((hostName, PORT_NUMBER))
recvSocket.listen(5)



print("Listening for client...")

(conn,addr)=recvSocket.accept()



print ("Test server listening on port {0}\n".format(PORT_NUMBER))
print("Connected to client at address {0}\n".format(addr))
print("Connection is ",conn)
```

Client Code:

```
import sys
from socket import socket,AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,gethostbyname 

hostname=gethostbyname('0.0.0.0')
print ("Creating")
sendsocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
print ("Connecting socket")
sendsocket.connect(('192.168.4.39',5060))
print ("connected")
data=input("Enter value")
sendsocket.sendto(data.encode('utf-8'),(SEND_IP,SEND_PORT))
```

Now the situation that I am facing is as follows:

**1st Scenario**

Server code is running on a Windows System and the client code is
running on a Linux system

***Result***: Client code is getting stuck after printing "Connecting socket"

**2nd Scenario**

Server Code is running on a Linux System and the Client code is running on
Windows system

***Result***: Getting output as Expected.

Why is this behaviour occurring? Does connect() function has any kind of problem or the code is having some problem?

**NOTE: Both Server and Client system is on the same Network. 192.168.4.39 is the IP Address where the server code is running.**

Comment: Are you running both the Windows and Linux code **at the same IP address**? If not, then why are you trying to connect to the same machine in the 1st scenario?

Comment: And if you *are* running it at the same IP address, you can't assign the same IP address to two entities.

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question but i will give you the info regardless
Server Code is running on IP 192.168.4.39
Client Code is running on IP 192.168.4.57

Comment: What machine has what IP address? If your linux machine is `192.168.4.39`, you need to adjust your connect call to use 192.168.4.57.

Comment: Linux has 192.168.4.57
Windows has 192.168.4.39

Comment: And when you swap the server and client did you update the IP address to connect to?

Comment: Yes... Absolutely...

Comment: Is there a firewall on the Windows machine? Did you open the 5060 port on it? There is nothing special about Linux and socket connecting.

Comment: Yes there is a firewall of an Antivirus software.
But one more information I should give you is that **ping 192.168.4.39** is working in Linux system. For that I have allowed protocol ICMP for the IP Address 192.168.4.57 in my Antivirus Software's  Firewall in Windows

Comment: [Update] 

I disabled the Windows Firewall Completely and now it's working properly...

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure client and server connected well.try ping each other.

Then do it manually like this:

Ssocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

should work